# Running into Nektos/Act error permission denied when running actions locally

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Pretty new to Nektos/act and in general running workflows locally and cant seem to find a solution to a permissions denied error when installing Node version 16. Here is the error I am running into when I run the following:

**Command:**

```
act -j release
```

**Error:**

```
docker exec cmd=[mkdir -p /var/run/act/actions/actions-setup-node@v1/] user= workdir=
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/act/actions': Permission denied
```

**Yaml (Example)**

```
name: Release Example
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_SECRET}}

      - name: Use version 16 of Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Pre Install
        run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}"> ~/.npmrc

      - name: Install
        run: npm ci
        env:
          PRIVATE_SECRET: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_SECRET}}

      - name: Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_SECRET}}
          PRIVATE_SECRET: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_SECRET}}
          REGISTRY_TOKEN: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_SECRET}}
        run: npx semantic-release
```

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried setting the user to root on the container for example

   ```
   container:
     image: ghcr.io/catthehacker/ubuntu:full-20.04
     options: --user root
   ```
2. I have tried setting sudo in steps

   ```
    - run: sudo chown runner:docker /var/run/docker.sockenter
   ```
3. I have tried passing the secrets via [acts](https://github.com/nektos/act#flags) flags
4. I have tried setting the working directory and setting env auth override to true
5. I have checked issues related to this topic on the [repo](https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/935) and it seems like others are facing the same issue but I have not been able to figure out a solution.

**NOTE:** This is all working on GitHub, but fails locally with the error mentioned above. Trying hard to test locally to not muddy up my repo with broken commits. **Any help is greatly appreciated**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug with the recent release. I confirm that downgrading to 0.2.24 fixed this issue.

https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/935#issuecomment-1035261208

```
brew remove act
cd $(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
git checkout 3ab2604b1e630d4eccab40d0e78f29bd912a72b8 -- act.rb
brew install act
brew pin act
git checkout HEAD -- act.rb
act --version # make sure it's 0.2.24
```

Comment: This doesn't downgrade 0.2.26 to 0.2.24 for me. It keeps installing 0.2.26.

Comment: I had to set HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_UPGRADE or it would overwrite the changes to act.rb before installation.

Answer (score 0):

For me running this command works:

```
sudo chown 1001 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I think they are working on this, please see the end of this [issue](https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/724).